# set other account in accounting module

Tags: odoo

I am trying to set default account for some fields for that i write some code like

```
<!--        1.Income account–311000                 -->
    <record forcecreate="True" id="property_account_income_product" model="ir.property">
        <field name="name">property_account_income</field>
        <field name="fields_id" search="[('model','=','product.template'),('name','=','property_account_income')]"/>
        <field eval="'account.account,'+str(account_account_456)" name="value"/>
        <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_company"/>
    </record>
```

in account.account.template i write code like

```
<record model="account.account.template" id="account_account_456">
              <field name="name">INCOME FROM SALES</field>
              <field name="code">311000</field>
              <field name="type">other</field>
              <field name="user_type" ref="account.data_account_type_income"/>
              <field name="reconcile" eval="False"/>
              <field name="parent_id" ref="account_account_256"/>
         </record>
```

but after update database it sets different account
i don't know why but correct account are not set
pleas help me
thanks...

Now i got exact Problem Firstly i put record in **account.account.template** this record is also automatically added into **account.account** and when i am trying to add record into **ir.property**   search that Account into account.account.template take id and display record from account.account

so the problem is id mismatch in **account.account** and **account.account.template**
how to resolve this problem and sorry for English

Answer (score 0):

This is because you must having multiple entries in `model="ir.property"` for field `property_account_income_product` for your company so when you try an see the values for the a/c you will find the first value get set on field as your record may be second in list, so it get not selected.

Comment: I am trying for field property_account_income not for  property_account_income_product and there is no other entry for field property_account_income